# Conditionally ignore a field from the source if a condition is true on destination

Tags: automapper

I'm using `Automapper` to update a series of entities from a DTO. However, there are some properties that I do not want to update from the DTO, if certain conditions apply. For example, the entity has a date in the past.

Comment: So you're specifically looking at the cases where you provide an existing destination object -- not where Automapper creates the destination for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PreCondition option.  Here's a simple example:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping of `Name` will only happen if the current year of `LastUpdated` is 2015:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.PreCondition((rc) => ((Dest) rc.DestinationValue).LastUpdated.Year == 2015))
    .ForMember(d => d.LastUpdated, o => o.Ignore());

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

In the code below, the "dest" object will retain the name "Larry":

```
var src = new Source {Name = "Bob", Age = 22};
var dest = new Dest {Name = "Larry", LastUpdated = new DateTime(2014, 10, 11)};

Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, dest);
```

If you change the year for `LastUpdated` to 2015, the `Name` property gets updated to "Bob".

Comment: What's the difference between `Condition` and `PreCondition`

Comment: @blockhead, `Condition` only passes the value of the current destination property being mapped in the `DestinationValue` property.  `PreCondition` gives you the entire destination object for `DestinationValue`.